# How do I prevent users from accidentally deploying to too many tenants in Octopus?

Tags: octopus-deploy

Over the years we’ve had a few instances of Octopus Deploy users accidentally releasing a version to multiple environments, based on a tenant tag.

I usually tell users to check that the Tenant list under ‘Preview and customize’ only contains the 1 environment intended, but we still have some slip through where Octopus deploys to 20+ environments, which I then need to roll back.

Is there a way to alert users when there are more than 1 Tenant in the list, so they can sense check it before proceeding to deploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with a PowerShell script, which you add as a deployment step. The script will check for more than one tenant, and alert the user to perform manual intervention if it detects more than 1 target

To have the script work successfully, you must perform the following:

- Set a Secret Project Variable named APIKey with the value of an API-Key with access to the deployments within that space.
- Change the `$octopusURL` variable in the Script to match your Octopus Hostname.
- Place the Script at the beginning of your deployment inside a "Run A Script" step.
- Create a Manual Intervention step as the 2nd process step in your project with the run condition set to: `#{Octopus.Action[Run a Script].Output.MultipleTenants}`
- If you decide to change the name of the step that contains the Script below, be sure to place the step name within the square brackets ([]) on the run condition variable.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";

# Define working variables
$octopusURL = "http://OctopusURL"
$octopusAPIKey = "$APIKey"
$header = @{ "X-Octopus-ApiKey" = $octopusAPIKey }
$spaceId = $OctopusParameters["Octopus.Space.Id"]

# Get Release Deployment Data
$releaseData = Invoke-RestMethod -method GET -uri "$($octopusURL)/api/$($spaceId)/releases/#{Octopus.Release.Id}/deployments/" -Headers $header

# Get DateTime of Deployment Created
$checkDate = Get-Date $OctopusParameters["Octopus.Deployment.Created"] -format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

write-host "The following tenants are being deployed to at $($checkDate):"

# Instantiate list
$tenantList = @()

# ForEach Deployment Item inside the Release do the following:
foreach($item in $releaseData.Items){

    # Generate compatible DateTime for comparison with deployment Time
    $date = Get-Date $item.Created.Substring(0,19) -format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

    # Check date equivalence, if equal then do the following:
    if($date -eq $checkDate){
    write-host "The tenant with ID: $($item.TenantId) is included in this deployment at $($date)."
 
    # Add tenant to list
    $tenantList = $TenantList + ($item.TenantId)

    # If a release is redeployed, previous tenants may exist in the JSON items, this elseif generates the list of tenants deployed to previously, but not in THIS deployment:
    }elseif($tenantList -notcontains $item.TenantId){
        write-host "The tenant with ID: $($item.TenantId) is not included in this deployment as it was deployed at $($date)."
    }
}

# Condition check list size, create output variable if more than one Tenant.
if($tenantList.Count -gt 1){
Set-OctopusVariable -name "MultipleTenants" -value "True"
}
```

Comment: Note. This answer was provided by Adam Hollow @ Octopus Deploy Support. I am sharing it here incase it helps other users of Octopus.